# How to package my scripts and code into one homogeneous and comprehensive software?

Tags: python, iot, software-design

We have an IoT that does what it's supposed to. however, everyone in our team wrote a piece of its code and scripts and the result was a bunch of scripts codes that work independently. some in Python, other in shell and Java.

We are thinking to rewrite everything in Python. My question is how can we package all those scripts and codes into one piece of software where each piece of code
talk to one another.

What is done in the industry today?

Comment: To have the scripts talk to each other, have them talk to each other. Putting things in a package is a good way to bundle things.

Comment: @Mad Physicist the question is how? what's the approach used now? any tutorial or place I can start from?

Comment: Yes, but stack overflow is not the right venue for open ended questions like that. A search engine will give you infinitely more bang for the buck. The answers you get here, if any, will be limited by the information you provide. You are better off doing some research on your own and adapting it to your specific needs, which only you know.